# Find out which domain is used in database for Joomla

Tags: php, sql, database, joomla

Is there a way to find out in a Joomla database for which it is used, in the case of Wordpress there is the wp_options -> siteurl table. Does Joomla have this?

Comment: Please join [joomla.se] Stack Exchange and ask your Joomla questions there.

Answer (score 0):

Domain is only available in `configuration.php` file at the Joomla root folder.

Comment: Yes, thank you but I was hoping to reverse-engineer the domain from the database on the mysql-server (phpmyadmin). Not from the file structure on the FTP-server.

Comment: that's what i assumed but domain information is not stored in database.

Answer (score 0):

there is no requirement for the website in the db, however there are a number of tables that may contain it.

You might want to check the #_redirect table if the plugin was ever enabled you should find it there. Also worth looking into is #_menu and any SEO extension tables

Please consider these are not used or required byJoomla so they  could belong to the staging phase of the website and thus contain a wrong url. I have found sites with several domains in their db.